# Comparing Different Weighted Averages

Tags: inequality

Let $n$ be a positive integer. We call an $n$-tuple $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n) \in [0, 1]^n$ a distribution if $a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n = 1$. Suppose that we have two distributions $a = (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$ and $b = (b_1, b_2, ..., b_n)$ satisfying
$$ \frac{a_1}{b_1} \leq \frac{a_2}{b_2} \leq  ... \leq \frac{a_n}{b_n}.$$
Given any sequence $0 \leq d_1 \leq ... \leq d_n$, is it the case that
$$ \sum_{k = 1}^n b_k d_k \leq \sum_{k = 1}^n a_k d_k?$$

Any hints, comments, solutions are appreciated.